# Compare date range with dates in table VBA

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, date

I am using MS Access as front-end for a MySQL server database. In database i have a table called PubHol (meaning Public Holidays) listing the dates dd/mm/yyyy of public holidays. I have a form (linked to a separate table) where i enter course_start date and course_end date. I would like to create a function which triggers itself on lostfocus of a field where the function checks whether the date range entered course_start and course_end coincides with a day listed in PubHol. For example if a client has course start 01/01/2012 and course end 15/01/2012 and there is a date in PubHol falling between for ex 10/01/2012 I want to receive a MsgBox saying something. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you're storing the dates as *strings*? If so, why not store them as *dates* using a more appropriate field?

Comment: Hi. I am storing the dates of public holidays in a table as dates. The course_start and course_end dates are in another table (Main_Data_Table) which is basically the booking form. What i need is that when employees enter a new booking and they enter course_start and Course_end which coincide with one of the dates in the PubHol table they receive a message saying bla bla bla ... thanks

Comment: Right, so when you gave the "dd/mm/yyyy" part, that was completely irrelevant, right? It's not like the text format is *actually* how they're stored?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to issue a `BETWEEN` query to MySQL:

```
SELECT HolidayDate FROM PubHol
WHERE HolidayDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

... and fill in the parameters for the query with the `Course_Start` and `Course_End` values you're interested in. (I'm assuming VBA can handle parameterized queries.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you used a date data type and not a string data type in your db, testing holidays which fall into a date range would look like this in VBA

```
Dim condition As String
Dim course_start As Date, course_end As Date

course_start = ...
course_end = ...
condition = "[Holiday] Between #" & Format$(course_start,"yyyy\/mm\/dd") & _
            "# AND #" & Format$(course_end,"yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
If DCount("*", "PubHol", condition) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ...
End If
```

---

I found this function in my Access libraries

```
Public Function JetSqlDate(ByVal d As Variant) As String
    If IsNull(d) Then
        JetSqlDate = "NULL"
    Else
        JetSqlDate = Format$(d, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy hh\:nn\:ss\#")
    End If
End Function
```

Using it simplifies making the condition

```
condition = "[Holiday] Between " & JetSqlDate(course_start) & _
            " AND " & JetSqlDate(course_end)
```

---

Note: If the MySQL tables are linked into the Access DB with ODBC you can just use the Access (Jet) SQL syntax. Access (or the ODBC-Driver to be precise) will translate it to MySQL syntax automatically.

Comment: Many thanks, will try it out tomorrow morning and revert. Thanks once again

Comment: *If* the platform supports using typed values and parameterized SQL, I'd *strongly* recommend using both instead of relying on string formats and including the data in the SQL.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I agree that parameterized queries are usually better; however, here I am working with a value typed as `Date` and we have a desktop scenario. So SQL-injection should not be a problem. Moreover, I want to use the handy built-in `DCount` function. I wonder, if SQL-injection is possible at all through `DCount` and through ODBC?